# MySQL group by without column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table contains user infos.

```
mysql> desc accounts;
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cid         | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username    | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mysignature | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_admin    | varchar(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Normal group by statement always follows by one or more column names like below:

```
select * from accounts group by cid;
```

Just an example, in general `group by` works with Aggregate functions like `sum()`.

I have found some follows by an expression without column names which I cant understand:

```
mysql> select username from accounts group by now();
+----------+
| username |
+----------+
| admin    |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am new in MySQL. How does this query work ?
Thanks.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause contains one or more *expressions* which can simply be column names, but can also be anything else that will be evaluated for each record to determine in which group the record belongs.  In the case of `NOW()`, the result will be the same for every record and thus all records will end up in the same group; unless every such record has the same value of `username`, that which will be selected will be *indeterminate*.  See [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: How is that a 'normal group by statement'? In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of GROUP BY is entirely inappropriate. Unlike many other RDMS's MySQL tries its best not to throw an error when fed garbage. The wisdom of this is questionable and vigorously debated. Your query is meaningless so trying to explain it is (possibly) pointless and (certainly) beyond my paygrade.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's expression. It compares expression results instead of column values for the grouping.

Comment: Is there some tools that I can track SQL query step by step ?

Answer (score 0):

`now()` function with the group by is not so effective.

It will always return the first row from the selected data.

You always need to specify the column name in the `group by` clause in query. Here are [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html) of tutorial of group by.
It specify that which aggregate function you can use with group by.

`now()` with group by return that will select the data from the query and match the first and it will be first row.